# Ability to unread leads

Tags: leads

Below is the scenario which I need to handle

I would like the ability to mark leads as "read". There are instances where the sales team has acted on the lead but not via Salesforce. Is there a way I can simply go in and mark the lead as read instead of having to ask them to do so? I do not want the system to automatically change the status of leads that are not mine simply by opening them

Any ideas how shall we achieve this?

Comment: What is "Read"? is it custom field that you added?  did you tried anything?what is problem that you are facing?

Comment: It's a standard [status](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004993&language=en_US).

Comment: In order to be able to help you we need to know how you expect Salesforce to know that a lead was handled outside of salesforce. Do you have an integration, something sent to salesforce once  the lead is handled outside of salesforce? If you do not have a way to let SF know the lead was handled elsewhere you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the field IsUnreadByOwner to false. Something like this:

```
List<lead> leadsToMarkAsRead = [select id, IsUnreadByOwner from lead where id in:leadIdList];
for(Lead l: leadsToMarkAsRead){
    l.isUnreadByOwner = false;    
}
update leadsToMarkAsRead;
```

where leadIdList is a list of lead IDs to be marked as read.